# Symbol not found _authenticatePlayer

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, dyld

I know there are similar questions, but none of my research or those solutions have applied to me yet.

I am trying to make a build of my app on iOS through xCode 7.0.1. After upgrading unity I started getting this error:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _authenticatePlayer   Referenced from:
>   /Users/bstidwell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F7EAC5FD-EEEE-45AF-A486-2E729154885C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9B914EA1-1E06-4226-811D-F6C034B43B8B/sinasprite.app/sinasprite
>   Expected in: flat namespace  in
>   /Users/bstidwell/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F7EAC5FD-EEEE-45AF-A486-2E729154885C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9B914EA1-1E06-4226-811D-F6C034B43B8B/sinasprite.app/sinasprite

I am pretty new to iOS development so I really don't understand a large portion of what to do. It seems it says it is referenced from the same place that it is expected to be, so I assume it is missing?

I have tried the foundation.Framework fix and it didn't work. I have also looked on multiple other sites. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!